# ASP.NET configuration tool doesn't work in folders with special characters

Tags: asp.net, configuration

it seems that I just solved my problem why I couldn't use the ASP.NET Configuration Tool in VS2008. It seems this tool doesn't work when the aps.net solution is located in a folder containing special characters - spaces for example. Actually, I didn't discover this myself. I found it on various forums.

What puzzles me though is that my VS2008 puts new projects (web projects included) into my documents folder which deep down at the root starts with Documents And Settings\[User]\Documents (on XP at least). Am I missing something here or does the default really makes using the ASP.NET Configuration tool impossible to use?

Thanks for you feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very little I use the ASP.Net Configuration tool for anymore (all it does is modify your web.config), and a lot of things can flub it up, but...

Most of my projects have spaces in the path at some point, and I've never had any trouble with that part.

My advise would be to figure out what it is that you want to do, and learn how to make that change directly in the web.config.  (I can hear the down-modding as I write this)

Comment: What about when he wants to modify ASP.NET Membership accounts?